# Why doesn’t my DigitalOcean load balancer forward traffic to Parse Servers?

Tags: load-balancing, port-forwarding, node.js, digital-ocean, parse-server

Today I created a load balancer and assigned to it 3 droplets (all 3 host parse servers), but it doesn't transfer the traffic to them. It doesn’t even pass the health checks!

All 3 of my parse servers, have 22 and 1337 as their only open inbound ports.

Here's the load balancer's setup.
[image: Screenshot-at-Mar-16-01-23-17.png]

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my health check port; apparently, it needs to be the same with the forwarding port, 1337 in my case!